# Which parent element disturbs my width: 100%

Tags: css, width, element, parent

When the viewport of my browser is at 1300 pixels, my browser gets a horizontal scrollbar. If I scroll horizontally, there is just a white space. I´ve already tried to figure out, which parent element prevents these elements of beeing "width: 100%".

The site is: http://www.despicable-clothing.de

Is any parent element the problem, or is it something else?

Thanks in  advance!

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS here in your post rather than linking to an external website. This helps us answer you faster as well as provides context for those who find this question down the road, after you've fixed the issue on your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden` to this: `#untermenu` and it should work perfect

Comment: It works wonderful! But I dont understand how you figured out that it was the #untermenu-div that made problems. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: when you don't have any idea on which div/element is the problem, start by eliminating some div structures and see what happens when they are gone. in this case I knew that you need an overflow:hidden, but I had to figure it out where you need it to be sure that you don't break anything else. Overflow:hidden on body tag is not a good fix, so usually try to find the div that has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

apply overflow style on body tag:

```
style="overflow: hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

set `min-width: 1351px;` for `body` tag.